# Zip NSData directly with SSZipArchive not working

Tags: ios, swift, zip, nsdata, ssziparchive

I try to save nsdata as a zipped file like:

```
 let zipArch = SSZipArchive(path: "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5F3152AA-F07A-4AD2-98A9-22051C524AF2/Library/")
 print(zipArch.writeData(andCryptedData, filename: "aFileName.zip", withPassword: "aPass"))
```

writeData gives me always false - If I save the file first in this folder and zip it after this, it will work - but I don't want to save the file temporary anywhere - I need a solution to save a NSData directly to a zip.

Comment: In the path, we can see the "5F3152AA-F07A-4AD2-98A9-22051C524AF2" that may change (on each compilation). You should use `NSLibraryDirectory` for instance.

Comment: that's what I'm already using.... I just added this path for this example.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to make nsdata directly to a zipped file is like that:

```
let zipArch = SSZipArchive(path: "path/to/library/directory/test.zip")
print(zipArch.open)
print(zipArch.writeData(aData!, filename: "aFileName.doc", withPassword: "aPass"))
print(zipArch.close)
```

print's just for checking if everything is created!